# Tooltip in title element not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a tooltip using JavaScript and Bootstrap. Now my problem is that when I try using `var t = document.getElementById('toolt').title; t = data[x].time;` it should put a title element on a html element which is doesn't.

Here's the full code:

```
<i data-toggle="tooltip" class="fa fa-info-circle" id='toolt'></i>
<script>
// Listen for output
socket.on('output', function(data) {
    if(data.length) {
        // Loop through results
        for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x = x + 1) {
            var message = document.createElement('div');

            var t = document.getElementById('toolt').title;
                t = data[x].time;

            message.setAttribute('class', 'chat-message');
            message.textContent = data[x].name + ': ' + data[x].message;

            // Append
            messages.appendChild(message);
            messages.insertBefore(message, info.firstChild);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: does `document.getElementById('toolt').title = data[x].time` make any differnece? any errors in your dev console? does the title attribute not get added to the html in your console at all? worked for me using firefox, what borwser/version?

Comment: Yes, the first option fixed it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: great, will add as an answer with an explination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becasue you are simply assiging a new value to the varaible, not changing the property of the object/html

```
 var t = document.getElementById('toolt').title;
     t = data[x].time;
// what you are doing here is setting a varaible 't' as ""
// then setting it as data[x].time
```

you'd need the below code to set the html property value:

```
document.getElementById('toolt').title = data[x].time;
```

If you do need to store the html object for some reason, you'd want

```
var t = document.getElementById('toolt');
t.title = data[x].time;
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't assigns scalar variables by reference, only objects. In this code:

```
var t = document.getElementById('toolt').title;
```

... `t` is a **copy** of the `title` property, not a reference. Thus any further modification will alter the copy, not the original.